# Trouble passing TFS build number to MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I'm trying to get TFS to pass the build number to MSBuild but it looks like the environmental variables are not being parsed and I'm getting the following error:

'$(TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)' is not a valid version string.

The argument I'm using is:

/p:OctoPackPackageVersion=$(TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)

I've also tried using the build id but that doesn't get parsed either. If I type the same version number into the argument then the build completes successfully.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and TFS on Visual Studio Online. Please let me know if there any settings I can try change to resolve this.

Thanks very much

Comment: Which build system are you using, XAML or Task-based?

Answer (score 1):

That would be correct for the XAML build system. If you're using the newer build system instead, it would be `$(Build.BuildNumber)`.

Comment: Thanks but that still gives me the same error. I'm using DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml

Comment: I've just tried '$(BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)' which also doesn't work.

Comment: $(Build.BuildNumber) worked for me in the "MSBuild Argument" field of the "Visual Studio Build" build step in the new build system.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours I've solved this by changing the build process template to TfvcTemplate.12.xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread I know, but for anyone who has stumbled across this running TFS "15" RC2 or later, using tasks in vNext, the property I found that worked is $(BUILD_BUILDNUMBER) and can be utilised in the .proj files. InstallShield was causing me issues when trying to pass the build number into the ProductVersion...

Adding this line fixed my problem..

```
<InstallShieldProductVersion>$(BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)</InstallShieldProductVersion>
```